# iOSでユーザがある画面にどのくらいの時間を使ったか計測する方法について

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics-api, mixpanel, logging

お世話になっております。

あるiOSのゲームでプレーヤーがある場面でどのくらいの時間を使ったかを調査したいと思っています（依頼されました）。

やや特殊なところとして、これはゲームなので、UIViewControllerの滞在時間とは異なります。同一UIViewControllerの中にステージ1, 2, 3, ... が表示されます。その各ステージにどのくらい時間を要したかを調査したいということです。例えば一般的にステージ12はかなり時間をかける傾向があるが、ステージ31はすぐに解けるようだ、と知りたいのです。

できれば、Google AnalyticsやFirebaseのようなものでうまくイベントを記録していきたいと思っています。これはバックエンドを作るのにかなり手間がかかると予想されるからで、うまく代理してくれるツールがあればそれに頼りたいと思っています。

こうした用途に適したツールをご存知でしたら紹介していただけると幸いです。指針だけでもいただけたら調査致します。

よろしくお願いします。